# Failed to apply plugin ‘propdeps’. No such property: COMPILE_CONFIGURATION_NAME for class: org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew

I am trying to update Gradle in a springboot application from verison 6.8 to latest(as of today 7.5) and I am facing the below error

```
Failed to apply plugin ‘propdeps’.
No such property: COMPILE_CONFIGURATION_NAME for class: org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin
```

What is the correct approach to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle 7 requires the property `COMPILE_CONFIGURATION_NAME`

Thus `prodeps` plugin is not compliant with Gradle 7 runtime. According to `mvnrepository`, this has not been updated since 2018 and on `jfrog` the last release was actually published in 2017. No newer version of the plugin seems to exist.

You need to determine what the plugin was used for and see if Gradle 7 now provides the capability, if not research for another plugin candidate providing a similar set of features.